# 100% width image in hero unit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to place an image inside the .hero-unit that takes up 100% of the unit.  This means that it would scale according to the overal window size.

Right now i have the  in there, but it looks like there's 100px padding to the right of the image.  If i adjust the image max-width: 100% to something larger, it does not scale accordingly.

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <img src="images/landscape.png">
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to remove the padding on the right, but also preserve the auto-resizing capabilities of bootstrap?

Comment: can you show the test page , would be easier to help

Comment: Any reason why you're using Bootstrap 2 and not 3?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned use the following selector :

```
.hero-unit img {
 width: 100%; height: auto;   
}
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/MgcDU/2145/

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%; height: auto;` should work, as long as the container div's resizing according to window width is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

Here's one jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shail/5YD2J/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x400">
 </div>
</div>

.hero-unit {
     padding:6px;
  }
```

You need to have your image in good resolution , scaling an image with small width and height will lead to bad stretched dimensions and wont look good .